# jQuery .delay() not delaying the .html() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a little javascript trick to fade out a div, replace its content, and fade it back in.  The .html event is replacing the content before the fadeOut is complete...

```
$("#products").fadeOut(500)
              .delay(600)
              .html($("#productPage" + pageNum).html())
              .fadeIn(500);
```

It *appears* that the `.html()` is not being delayed by the `.delay()` method.

Comment: `.delay()` only works on animation events, so `.delay()` out of that context will do absolutely nothing for you. Frustrating, I know.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351574/3779853 for `fadeOut(500).wait(500).html(..)`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`delay` will work for your case when used with the [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) like this:

```
$("#products").fadeOut(500)
    .delay(600)
    .queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html("hahahhaha");
        n();
    }).fadeIn(500);​
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/n7j8Y/

Comment: Two things - Why doesn't `.delay()` work on `.html()` and what does `n()` do?

Comment: @DerekAdair - Not sure why this is necessary, but it seems to be. If you manually trigger an event like ```$('#example').trigger('click');```, it doesn't work without the ```n()```. It likely has to do with some sort of return value.

Comment: `n()` stands for 'next queue item', according to the [**docs on queue**](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), this dequeue's the item and triggers the next animation item.

Comment: Is this still the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the "queue" way it's ok,
But this javascript solution works better for me:

```
    setTimeout (function(){
      $("#products").html('Product Added!');
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

you could change it to make the change when the fadeOut is completed using the fcallback function parameter.

so it becomes:

```
$("#products").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).html($("#productPage" + pageNum).html());
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```