# How to delay 5 seconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript function:

```
function validateAddToCartForm(object) {
   value = $(".product-detail-qty-box").val();
   if(!isInt(value) || value < 1) {
           $(".product-detail-error").show();
           return false;
   } else {
           $(".product-detail-error").hide();

           var product_name = $("#product_detail_name").text();
           var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog">\ ' + product_name + '</div>');
       NewDialog.dialog({            
           modal: true,
           title: "title",
           show: 'clip',
           hide: {effect: "fadeOut", duration: 1000}
       });

   }
   return true;
}
```

I need to pause 3 to 5 seconds before returning true, because I want to show a New Dialog box for a while. How can I implement this delay?

Comment: Why do you need to add the delay?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722791/wait-or-sleep-function-in-jquery

Comment: I call validateAddToCartForm method from Dialog. The main dialog will exit when return true. I want to show sub dialog for a while before main dialog is closed. That why I want to delay for a while to remain main dialog.

Comment: the callback is only way bro

Answer (score 1):

The only way to simulate delay in js is callback on timeout.

change the function  to:

```
function validateAddToCartForm(object,callback) {
   value = $(".product-detail-qty-box").val();
   if(!isInt(value) || value < 1) {
           $(".product-detail-error").show();
           callback(false);
   } else {
           $(".product-detail-error").hide();

           var product_name = $("#product_detail_name").text();
           var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog">\ ' + product_name + '</div>');
       NewDialog.dialog({            
           modal: true,
           title: "title",
           show: 'clip',
           hide: {effect: "fadeOut", duration: 1000}
       });

   }
   setTimeout(function() {callback(true);},5000);
}
```

where you call it you should do something like:

instead of

```
function somefunct() {
    //code before call
    if (validateAddToCartForm(object)) {
       //process true
    } else {
       //process false
    }
    //rest of the function 
}
```

place something like:

```
function somefunct() {
    //code before call
   validateAddToCartForm(object,function(ret) {
    {
     if (ret) {
        //process true
     } else {
        //process false
     }       
    //rest of the function 
    }
}
```

---

In to answer to your comment.
I assume:

- that you want to prevent click event if validate false,
- that all elements that you added onclick="..." have class ".clickme",

the element now looks like

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="return validateAddToCartForm(this)" class="clickme" />
```

---

so 1st change the element to

```
<input type="submit" class="clickme" />
```

add to your javascript the following:

```
//this handle original click, drop it out, and only pass after validation
$(function () {
    $('.clickme').click(function (e) {
        var $t = $(this);
        //if event triggered return true        
        if (e.isTrigger) return true;
        validateAddToCartForm(this, function (ret) {
            if (ret) {
                $t.trigger('click');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

also I suggest to use "submit" event on the form itself instead of "click" ([the demo of submit](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/erneH/))

Comment: Thanks. I call the function in onclick="return validateAddToCartForm(this);". So how shall I call your method in onlick.

Comment: oh.... this is about form ? I will place to answer, you should not do `onclick="";`  with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blocking, you can use `seTimeout` to remove the `#MenuDialog` after a certain time.

```
function validateAddToCartForm(o){
  var keep_dialog_time = 5 * 1000; // five seconds.
  // Whatever...

  /* Use setTimeout(function, milliseconds) to delay deletion of #MenuDialog.
     This will get executed keep_dialog_time milliseconds after this call, and
     won't block. */
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#MenuDialog').hide(); // maybe there is another function to do this, I'm not a jQuery guy really.
  }, keep_dialog_time);
  return true;
}
```

JavaScript is single threaded. This means, when you block, you block the everything. Thus, the DOM uses an event loop model, where callbacks are assigned to events. Such a model is also present in [node.js](http://nodejs.org) too. Above, because `setTimeout` does not block, code after that call will continue to run without waiting the function we passed to `setTimeout` to get executed.

I'd suggest to study [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) in depth to get more comfortable with web front-end programming. You may use various search engines to find out cool documentation.

Comment: OP wrote *Currently I need to suspend or delay 3 or 5 seconds before return true.* do you get it in your code ?

Comment: @eicto I believe he wants to show the dialog for a while (quoting OP: *...Because I want to show New Dialog for a while...*). This code should do this.

Comment: it is not clean which dialog he want to show for a while :) but anyway, if he want to close it after timeout it should be called as

`NewDialog.dialog('close');`