# jQuery .delay() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've the following JavaScript snippet:

```
$("#dashboard").addClass("standby").delay(3000).removeClass("standby");
$(".active").removeClass("active");
$("." + target).addClass("active");
$(".showDiv").removeClass("showDiv").addClass("hide");
$("#" + target).removeClass("hide").addClass("showDiv");
```

While `#dashboard` is in *standby*, it should handle all this CSS-Class changes. After this changes, it should display the `#dashboard` again. So I set `delay()` between the add and remove of the `standby`-class. To see if it works I added the too long duration of 3sek.

But it doesn't delay! Why it don't? I don't see it...

Comment: delay is used for queued items as animated elements, here, there is nothing to delay

Comment: possible duplicate of [wait() or sleep() function in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722791/wait-or-sleep-function-in-jquery)

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here of how javascript executes, but that's not really what is causing the problem here. As further research to help you better understand how javascript code works, i suggest this video, it explains the javascript event loop which is an integral part to how javascript operates. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: I already have, it'll either get accepted or declined, only time will tell.

Comment: Clicked "reopen" ; expected result described at Question could be achieved using `.delay(duration, queueName)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will only work on actions that go through the animation pipeline, and won't have an influence on the timing of instant atomic operations like that. In order to delay things such as adding or removing classes, then you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout).

> the .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue.
>
> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: _"delay will only work on actions that go through the animation pipeline"_ `.delay()` could be utilized outside of animation pipeline using `.queue()` , `.dequeue()`

Answer (score 5):

`.delay()` will only delay animations in jQuery.
To set an actual delay, you might want to use `setTimeout()`.

```
let cancelId;
// ...
cancelId = window.setTimeout(function() {
  // ... do stuff ... 
}, 3000);

// If you want to cancel prematurely, use `window.clearTimeout`
if (cancelId) {
  window.clearTimeout(cancelId);
}
```

This will execute the code in `... do stuff ...` in 3 seconds (3000 miliseconds)

Answer (score 3):

Delay won't work the way you expect it to on these line:

```
$("#image1").delay(9000).attr("src", "image/image1.jpg");
$("#image1").delay(9000).attr("src", "image/image2.jpg");
```

It will run the attribute change immediately. Why? Because the attribute change isn't part of the "animation". Delay can only be used with with animating functions.

If you only need two images, it might be easiest for you to have two images stacked together, and fade them in and out as needed.

If you want to expand this to many images, try using the more robust ".animate" function to fade in and out. "Animate" can be given a callback function that will be called when complete.

Comment: _"Delay can only be used with with animating functions."_ fwiw `.delay()` could also be used with `.queue()` , `.dequeue()` without animating an element

Comment: Yes, guest271314, I suppose it can, and that could also help solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

As stated ... delay won't work the way you expect ...
Here is how it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var audio = new Audio('sang3.mp3');
    audio.play();

    $("#image1")
        .hide()
        .attr("src", "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250")
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .queue(function(next) { 
          $(this).attr("src", "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-2&w=350&h=250")
          next(); 
        })
        .fadeIn(1000); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" id="image1">
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>All your delays start on `$(document).ready();`</s>

```
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3000);
$("#image1").delay(9000).attr("src", "image/image1.jpg"); 
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
$("#image1").delay(9000).attr("src", "image/image2.jpg");
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3000);
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
```

Think of it this way. When doc is ready, JS start executing whatever is inside that function, first delay it executes is this: `$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3000);`

That will START a delay of 5000 ms and then a `fadeOut()` with a duration of 3000 ms. That fadeOut is synchronus to the delay, but the next line of code is completely asynchronous to this one.

Then it procceeds to the next line. And so on. It won't wait to your delay to finish, it simply starts counting on the background.

`.delay()` DOES stack when applied to the same element: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wu9fdg2/)

I leave this just in case someone is confused as I was

Comment: Well that does makes sense now, but how could a task like this then be done? I have seen people use `setTimeout` also seen people use `setInterval`, and i tried to figure out how these could do the trick, but unfortunately without success. Could you give a brief example, how this could be done? what would you suggest.

Comment: Unlike native JS timeouts `delay()` in jQuery stacks, so this explanation is incorrect.

Comment: The ".delay" function works correctly, as expected, when using them on the same object like she is. This isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `.queue()`

```
  $("#image1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3000, function() {
      $(this).delay(9000, "task" ).queue("task", function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image/image1.jpg")
        .delay(5000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
          $(this).delay(9000, "task")
          .queue("task", function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "image/image2.jpg")
            .delay(5000).fadeIn(3000, function() {
               $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(3000)
            })
          }).dequeue("task")
        });
      }).dequeue("task")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like for what you are trying to do, you might want to take a look at CSS transitions:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

You can still have `.addClass()`, except now your class will utilize these transition properties, and you won't need .delay().

Answer (score 0):

Usually we need to do things before removing the standby state, so we remove the class in an ajax callback :

```
$("#dashboard").addClass("standby");
$.get('urltoget',function(data){
  if(data)
    $("#dashboard").removeClass("standby");
  else
    $("#dashboard").removeClass("standby").addClass('error');
})
```