# Javascript running tasks chronologically

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does javascript run the tasks?

I've recently started programming javascript, and after playing around with this, what i thought, simple project. That simply play some music, while some pictures is shown with a few seconds between.

In most languages I have used, the tasks are finished before the next one starts, but it doesn't seem like it's the same as in JS. In my code below, you only get to see "image/image2.jpg", not "image/image1.jpg for some reason.

Why isn't this working and how can this be done in a simple way?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45hurvsk/)

Html:

```
<img src="image/image1.jpg" id="image1" style="display:none;">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var audio = new Audio('sang3.mp3');
audio.play();


$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3000);
$("#image1").delay(9000).attr("src", "image/image1.jpg"); //This Image is never seen
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);

$("#image1").delay(9000).attr("src", "image/image2.jpg"); //But this one is
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeIn(3000);
$("#image1").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Comment: @KevinB At linked "duplicate of" accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522406/jquery-delay-doesnt-work _"delay will only work on actions that go through the animation pipeline,"_  `.delay()` could be utilized outside of jQuery animation using `.queue()` , `.dequeue()`

Comment: Yes, but it's the same problem. That information would be useful in the linked duplicate too, might be worth putting your answer there. Could also flag a mod to merge it so you keep your votes.

Comment: @KevinB Included comment at linked duplicate . _"Could also flag a mod to merge it so you keep your votes."_ Not certain how to do this ? , how became marked duplicate where at `.delay()` , documentation http://api.jquery.com/delay/#delay-duration-queueName _"A string containing the name of the queue. Defaults to fx, the standard effects queue."_