# How to make a wait in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying want to make jQuery wait before it slows down before It slides up

I tried using setTimeout but it didnt work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const myForm = $('#MyForm');
    const ul = $('items')
    const userList = $('#users');
    const AnswerInput = $('#Answer1').val();
    const msg = $('.msg');

    myForm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        if(AnswerInput === ''){
            msg.slideDown(2000)
            msg.addClass('error')
            msg.text('Please Enter an Answer')
            setTimeout(()=> msg.slideUp(), 2000)
        }

    })
});
```

here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="msg"></div>
        <form id="MyForm">
            <label for="answer"> Factorise x<sup>2</sup> + 5x + 6:</label>
            <input type="text" id="Answer1" class="inputText">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" id="clickBtn">

        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="users">
        <li>ghv</li>
        <li>jhbh</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There isnt an error I'd just like to know how to do it

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722791/wait-or-sleep-function-in-jquery/5722830 It will tell you how to 'wait()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function is what you're after.

```
msg
    .slideDown(2000)
    .delay(1000)
    .addClass('error')
    .text('Please Enter an Answer');
```

You should also look into [chaining](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/jquery-tutorial/jquery-chaining.php).

Answer (score 0):

replace your last line

```
setTimeout(()=> msg.slideUp(), 2000)
```

with

```
msg.delay(5000).slideUp();
```

replace 5000 with whaever time period you want, in miliseconds